# Mkvirtualenv not working after installing virtualenvwrapper on Windows

Tags: python, configuration, virtualenv

I installed both 'virtualenv' and 'virtualenvwrapper-win', and already setup a WORKON_HOME path, but when I try o run 'mkvirtualenv'it doesn't work.

cmd reports that the command isn't recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. What can I do to fix this issue? Below I wrote my pip list so you can check if I have all the correct packages. I'm also using python 3.11.5 on Windows 10.

Package               Version

---

distlib               0.3.7
filelock              3.12.4
pbr                   5.11.1
pip                   23.2.1
platformdirs          3.10.0
setuptools            65.5.0
stevedore             5.1.0
virtualenv            20.24.5
virtualenv-clone      0.5.7
virtualenvwrapper     4.8.4
virtualenvwrapper-win 1.2.7